# idea for web application in robotics

Tags: design, software

I am learning and I am interested robotics, but also I need to update my web development skills so the question is - is there any idea for good web application that could be connected with robotics - service robots, industrial robots etc. Maybe there already is some open source ongoing web application projects for robotics in which I can make contribution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

web based robotic simulator will be a good project. You can do simulators like [gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/) and [morse](https://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse/)

Answer (score 2):

There are the awesome "ROS Robot Web Tools" http://robotwebtools.org/ that give your ROS enabled robot a web interface.
We use it as high-level interface for many of our service robots, as we can then use a tablet computer to control them and don't have to care about the Tablet OS (Apple vs. MS vs. Android...)